# Bubble sort of a double array

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I know the bubble sort algorithm but my question is that what is the efficient code for making this sorting.
I have two models of this algorithm, I think both make bubble sort correctly but what is the best one of both with respect to memory space and time?!!

**Model A:**

```
public static void bubbleSort(double[] array){
    boolean sorted;
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++){
        sorted = true;
        for(int j = array.length - 1; j > i; j--){
            //swap
            if(array[j] < array[j - 1]){
                double temp = array[j - 1];
                array[j - 1] = array[j];
                array[j] = temp;
                sorted = false;
            }
        }
        if(sorted)
            break;
    }
}
```

**Model B:**

```
static void bubbleSort(double[] list) {
    boolean changed = true;
    do {
        changed = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < list.length - 1; j++)
            if (list[j] > list[j+1]) {
                //swap list[j] wiht list[j+1]
                double temp = list[j];
                list[j] = list[j + 1];
                list[j + 1] = temp;
                changed = true;
            }
    } while (changed);
}
```

Comment: What makes you think they're much different?

Comment: These are literally the same algorithm, you just added a do-while in model B.

Comment: So there is no preferred one?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to test both of them by a naïve way with `System.currentTimeMillis()` on 10000 random doubles.

```
long a = System.currentTimeMillis();
bubbleSort(array);
long b = System.currentTimeMillis() - a;
```

The first sort is little faster. I have tested always with random data separately.

> The first one in milliseconds: 179, 170, 185
>
> The second one in milliseconds: 292, 241, 244

The result is they work both same and fast. In general in Java there is not much need to find the fastest way at all costs. So don't worry and use any of them.

Comment: I think That, because the second one for every time it will cover the whole array regardless there is a part which is already sorted. Am I right?!